# Exporting vector to kml with ogr2ogr without extended data

Tags: convert, kml, export, ogr2ogr

If I convert a shapefile as kml in QGIS, GRASS or ogr2ogr directly, defining the name and/or description field with the -dsco tag, all columns in the attribute table of the input layer are exported to the kml as ExtendedData. Is there a way to create the kml with the Name and Description only, i.e., without the Extended data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to choose what goes over by using the -select option

Comment: Thanks, that works with ogr2ogr. I am not seeing an option to use this option in GRASS or QGIS.

Comment: It seems that if you use the -select option, you always need to include the columns you are using for "Name" and "Description"? This means these columns are included twice, as part of the Extended Data and as Placemark name and description.